# Have I gone wrong in populating this array?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to C, and I'm trying to print an array consisting of whole numbers upto a certain number(excluding this number) received as input. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n; int* k;
  k = &n;
  printf("Enter number");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int set[*k];
  for(int i=0; i<=n;i++){
    set[i]= i;
  }
  
}
```

I used `printf` in the last line with different inputs to check if it was working properly. I expected the output to be `0 1 2 3....n-1` but instead I got the output `1 2 3 4 ....n`. Doesn't the index of an array begin with a zero? What am I missing here?

Comment: In the future, please provide a [mcve]:  your program doesn't actually output anything except for "Enter number" so it is not complete.  The pointer `k` is not needed because you can just write `&n` instead of `k`, so your program is not minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indices in C do start at 0 but your loop is written incorrectly, and will let `i` iterate all the way up to `n`.  Replace `i <= n` with `i < n` so the loop stops after `n - 1`.